# How to get dependency injection to work in Liberty Profile

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, websphere-liberty

I cannot get dependency injection to work in Liberty Profile.  Here's what I have tried:

`server.xml` excerpts:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<managedExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/execSvc" id="Test1">
</managedExecutorService>
```

My code.  Note some of my many `@Resource` attempts.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource
{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloResource.class.getName());

//  @Resource(lookup="java:comp/env/concurrent/execSvc")
//  @Resource(lookup="java:comp/concurrent/execSvc")
//  @Resource(lookup="concurrent/execSvc")
//  @Resource(lookup="Test1")
//  @Resource(name="java:comp/concurrent/execSvc")
//  @Resource(name="concurrent/execSvc")
//  @Resource(name="Test1")
    @Resource       // with different names tried in <managedExecutorService> in server.xml 
    private ManagedExecutorService executor;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getMessage()
    {
        logger.info("HelloResource::getMessage()");

        int startTimeout = 10;
        String msg = "??";

        if (executor != null)
        {
            logger.info("Before Runnable Start");
            executor.execute(new RunnableTask(startTimeout));     
            logger.info("After Runnable Start");

            msg = "RunnableTask submitted";
        }
        else
        {
            logger.severe("executor is null");
            msg = "null executor";
        }

        return msg;
    }
}
```

I set a trace: `Naming=all:NamingService=all:org.apache.aries.jndi.*=all`

No clues that I can see in `trace.log`:

```
[10/7/19 15:30:05:297 MST] 000000d8  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper org= prod= component=
          CWWKZ0018I: Starting application JchJaxRsTestApp.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:298 MST] 000000d8  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARDeployedAppInfoFactoryImpl org= prod= component=
          CWWKZ0134I: The JchJaxRsTestApp application is using the loose application definition at the D:\jchprodtemp\WAS Liberty Profile - 19.0.0.9\wlp\usr\servers\JchJaxRsTest\apps\JchJaxRsTestApp.war.xml location.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:307 MST] 000000d8  > UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaColonNameService method=applicationMetaDataCreated id=50d82b52 org= prod= component=
          Entry  
          com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.internal.MetaDataEventImpl@7769e37e[com.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.internal.ApplicationMetaDataImpl@13d9cb7a[JchJaxRsTestApp], com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdaptableContainerImpl@5802a4c8 ( file:/D:/jch/Prog/Java/Eclipse/workspace-jee-2019-09-R/JchJaxRsTestApp/WebContent/ file:/D:/jchprodtemp/WAS%20Liberty%20Profile%20-%2019.0.0.9/wlp/usr/servers/JchJaxRsTest/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/71/data/cacheAdapt/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_44/.overlay/ )]
[10/7/19 15:30:05:307 MST] 000000d8  < UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaColonNameService method=applicationMetaDataCreated id=50d82b52 org= prod= component=
          Exit 
[10/7/19 15:30:05:337 MST] 000000d8  > UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaColonNameService method=moduleMetaDataCreated id=50d82b52 org= prod= component=
          Entry  
          com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.internal.MetaDataEventImpl@375e5fbb[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.metadata.WebModuleMetaDataImpl@5bcc4e41[JchJaxRsTestApp#JchJaxRsTestApp.war], com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdaptableContainerImpl@5802a4c8 ( file:/D:/jch/Prog/Java/Eclipse/workspace-jee-2019-09-R/JchJaxRsTestApp/WebContent/ file:/D:/jchprodtemp/WAS%20Liberty%20Profile%20-%2019.0.0.9/wlp/usr/servers/JchJaxRsTest/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/71/data/cacheAdapt/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_44/.overlay/ )]
[10/7/19 15:30:05:337 MST] 000000d8  < UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaColonNameService method=moduleMetaDataCreated id=50d82b52 org= prod= component=
          Exit 
[10/7/19 15:30:05:337 MST] 000000d8  > UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.container.service.naming.JavaColonNamespaceBindings method=<init> org= prod= component=
          Entry  
          java:module
          com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.naming.EJBJavaColonNamingHelper@41327753
[10/7/19 15:30:05:338 MST] 000000d8  < UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.container.service.naming.JavaColonNamespaceBindings method=<init> id=5cd245da org= prod= component=
          Exit  
          {}
[10/7/19 15:30:05:338 MST] 000000d8  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup org= prod= component=
          SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: JchJaxRsTestApp.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:338 MST] 000000d8  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost method=addWebApplication org= prod= component=
          SRVE0250I: Web Module JchJaxRsTestApp has been bound to default_host.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:338 MST] 000000d8  A UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl org= prod= component=
          CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/JchJaxRsTestApp/
[10/7/19 15:30:05:339 MST] 000000d8  A UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper org= prod= component=
          CWWKZ0003I: The application JchJaxRsTestApp updated in 0.042 seconds.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:341 MST] 00000074  > UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.container.service.naming.JavaColonNamespaceBindings method=<init> org= prod= component=
          Entry  
          java:comp/env
          com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.InjectionBindingClassNameProvider@145355cc
[10/7/19 15:30:05:341 MST] 00000074  < UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.container.service.naming.JavaColonNamespaceBindings method=<init> id=567006bd org= prod= component=
          Exit  
          {}
[10/7/19 15:30:05:341 MST] 00000074  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore class=SessionContextRegistryImpl method=getSessionContext org= prod= component=
          SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/JchJaxRsTestApp
[10/7/19 15:30:05:342 MST] 00000074  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.util class=IDGeneratorImpl method=IDGeneratorImpl org= prod= component=
          SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:350 MST] 00000074  I UOW= source=org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer org= prod= component=
          Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
[10/7/19 15:30:05:414 MST] 0000008c  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator org= prod= component=
          SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at D:\jchprodtemp\WAS Liberty Profile - 19.0.0.9\wlp\usr\servers\JchJaxRsTest\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[10/7/19 15:30:05:466 MST] 000000dc  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator org= prod= component=
          SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at D:\jchprodtemp\WAS Liberty Profile - 19.0.0.9\wlp\usr\servers\JchJaxRsTest\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[10/7/19 15:30:14:688 MST] 0000009b  I UOW= source=org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImplorg.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@7a1a844a[com.ibm.ws.org.apache.cxf.cxf.core.3.2:1.0.32.cl190920190905-0148(id=195)] org= prod= component=
          Setting the server's publish address to be /rest/
[10/7/19 15:30:14:692 MST] 0000009b  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper method=init org= prod= component=
          SRVE0242I: [JchJaxRsTestApp] [/JchJaxRsTestApp] [jch.jaxrstest.App]: Initialization successful.
[10/7/19 15:30:14:698 MST] 0000009b  I UOW= source=jch.jaxrstest.HelloResource org= prod= component=
          HelloResource::getMessage()
[10/7/19 15:30:14:698 MST] 0000009b  E UOW= source=jch.jaxrstest.HelloResource org= prod= component=
          executor is null
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest resources are not CDI enabled by default. Add the following to your `HelloResource` class `@RequestScoped` after `@Parth`

Then this will work:

```
    @Resource(lookup="concurrent/execSvc")
    ExecutorService executorService;
```

where `server.xml` contains the following (I'd strongly recommend only putting features that you really need, it will make server to start faster and consume less resources. `javaee-8.0` brings a lot of the stuff that you usually do not need):

```xml
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    ....
    <managedExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/execSvc"/>
```

in output from the class:

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        System.out.println("rest called: " + executorService);
        return "hello ";
    }
```

I can see executor correctly injected:

```
rest called: com.ibm.ws.concurrent.internal.ManagedExecutorServiceImpl@5f9d9066
```

Comment: Thank you.  Another option that I understand may work is to is to annotate the class with `@Stateless`.  Would `@RequestScoped` be preferable in this case?

Comment: @jch that depends. Annotating with `@Stateless` will work also, you are right. This would make a class an EJB bean with its benefits and potential drawbacks. So for example you would get automatic container transaction management, or security, if you need it, but you couldn't run it in simple web container (like Tomcat). Of course Liberty fully supports that. `@RequestScoped` makes it just CDI bean. So it is up to you. If you plan to use JDBC/JPA, EJB (`@Stateless`) would be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to add a *beans.xml* file to the web project and configure *beans.xml* with `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

See also this explanation: http://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2016/09/cdi-inject-beans-into-path-jax-rs.html